# how to convert an object with objects in only one object

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object:

```
var myObj = { abc:{a:1, b:2, c:3}, d:4 }
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
var newObj = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, id:'abc' }
```

Comment: Why is `myObj.d` is included in the conversion?

Comment: What is the logic for `id:'abc'`? Is it the first key?

Comment: @Eddie yes, the `id : 'abc'` will be always the first object key, and the only object inside main object

Comment: @choz this is the problem I'm facing, I need to put `myObj.d` together with the `myObj.abc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that data has only one deep level:**

- Check for the type number to add that kind of key-pair value `key: number`.
- Otherwise, add the id of the object and its key-pair values.

Use the function **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** to build the desired output and the function **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get the specific key for cases when an element follows this structure `id: {...}`.

Approach using **[`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

```js
var myObj = { abc:{a:1, b:2, c:3}, d:4 }

var result = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((a, k) => {
  if (typeof myObj[k] === 'number') return {...a, [k]: myObj[k]}
  return {...a, id: k, ...myObj[k]};
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Approach using the function **[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**

```js
var myObj = { abc:{a:1, b:2, c:3}, d:4 }

var result = Object.keys(myObj).reduce((a, k) => {
  if (typeof myObj[k] === 'number') return Object.assign(a, {[k]: myObj[k]});
  return Object.assign(a, {id: k}, myObj[k]);
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Both approaches are using **[`Computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)**

> The object initializer syntax also supports **computed property names**. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name. This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) syntax, which you might have used to read and set properties already.

**For example:**

```
{[k]: myObj[k]} // for example this will be converted to: {d: 4}
```

Comment: both approaches solved my problem, thanks for the very detailed explanations!